# Simple regex pattern in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need to match the first few characters of a string. The match is true if:

1. The first character is a letter (case insensitive)
2. The second character is either a digit or a letter
3. If the second character is a digit, the match is returned true
4. If the second character is a letter, the third character must be a digit
5. The pattern will ignore all other subsequent characters in the string

**Examples:**

```
AB1ghRjh  //true
c1        //true
G44       //true
Tt7688    //true
kGF98d    //false
4FG3      //false
4 5a      //false
RRFDE     //false
```

Would appreciate if anyone could supply an example.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This may be a beginner question, but it is clear and has a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^(?:[a-z]{2}|[a-z])\d.*$/im
```

*Explanation:*

```
^   # Start of string
    (?: # Start non-capturing group
        [a-z]{2}    # Two letter
        |   # OR
        [a-z]   # One letter
    )   # End of non-capturing group
    \d  # At least a digit here
    .*  # Escape all other characters
$   # End of string
```

`i` flag means case insensitive, `m` flag means make `^` & `$` do matching on each line (optional if your input hasn't newlines)

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/hP7hH9)

Then using `preg_match` function to match the strings:

```
if(preg_match("/^(?:[a-z]{2}|[a-z])\d.*$/i", "AB1ghRjh"))
{
    echo "Matched";
}
```

Comment: Wow - thanks to all replies, but especially to yours for taking the time to explain it all out and for including a sample PHP statement. Really appreciate it!!!

Comment: After 5 years I could see that the regex in this answer is somehow wordy. Someone could write `^[a-z]{1,2}\d` instead with `i` flag enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Regex would be

```
^[a-zA-Z](\d|[a-zA-Z]\d).*
```